# HIVE : Not in clause

Tags: hiveql, in-clause

Is there any way to execute the following Sql query in HiveQL?

```
select * from my_table
where (a,b,c) not in (x,y,z)
```

where a,b,c correspond respectively to x,y,z

Thanks:)

Comment: What do you mean by this construct?  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to break these down to separate conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   my_table
WHERE  a != x AND b != y AND c != z
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized the limitation of Hive that only one subquery can run inside a where clause and I followed your method to get things moving! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you intend?

```
where a <> x or b <> y or c <> z
```

Or this?

```
where a not in (x, y, z) and
      b not in (x, y, z) and
      c not in (x, y, z)
```

Or some other variation?

Comment: I meant the first variation that you suggested!